# Dynamically adding rows to a form without resetting previous row

Tags: javascript, html

Hi this is a second part to an early question. I need to add rows to a form consisting of a selection box. Each row of the form is a type of "Room" in a house and the user has to be able to add as many rooms as needed. I have it all working however if you fill in the 2nd room and then add a 3rd room it resets the selection box to its default for the 2nd room. I can see why it is doing this i just cant think of how to change the function so it keeps your previous selections intact. Note: i have the 1st row for the 1st room written in the HTML then this function(below) is called from a button click and adds the extra rooms.

```
function add_room() {

    var room_count = 0;
    write = document.getElementById('new_room')
    var roomSelect = '<select name="level[]" id="levels"' + room_count + '/> ';
    roomSelect += '<option>Basement</option>';
    roomSelect += '<option>Lower Level</option>';
    roomSelect += '<option>Main Floor</option>';
    roomSelect += '<option>2nd Floor</option>';
    roomSelect += '<option>3rd Floor</option></select>';
    write.innerHTML += roomSelect;
    room_count++;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: If you use `var room_count = 0;` in inside the function means, the id of select will be repeated, when you add more rooms... update this line in top and outside of add_room function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xM9Nh/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, although even fixing that still does not solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the magic of `.innerHTML +=`.

As you might have guessed, It's actually identical to `div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + moreHTML` - So the browser resets the HTML of the div. Including any selection, obviously.

I'd recommend you used `div.appendChild`. It doesn't change previously loaded HTML, and so won't change the user's selection.

```
function add_room() {
    var room_count = 0;
    write = document.getElementById('new_room');
    var roomSelect = document.createElement('select'); // create select node
    roomSelect.setAttribute("name", "level[]");
    roomSelect.setAttribute("id", "levels" + room_count);
    roomSelect.innerHTML = '<option>Basement</option>'+ //set the innerHTML (the options)
                   '<option>Lower Level</option>'+
                   '<option>Main Floor</option>'+
                   '<option>2nd Floor</option>'+
                   '<option>3rd Floor</option>'
    write.appendChild(roomSelect); //append the child
    room_count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! That worked!! Am i also able to use the .appendChild function to remove a "room" that was accidentally added?? Thanks again!

Comment: Your Welcome. That would be the `removeChild` function. `write.removeChild(document.getElementById('levels1'))`